# python not executing code written in __init__.py

Tags: python

I am having a print statement in `__init__.py` file and is not getting printed on the console when I am calling the libraries

My directory structure is as follow

- Dir_1 -----under that ---> I am having two folders names `libraries` and `scripts`  and a `__init__.py` file which is empty
- Libraries folder is having many python files and having `__init__.py` file
- I have added a print statement in `__init__.py` file. like print "*******************"
- I have added a created a new file say test.py under libraries folder and having below code in that

  class TEST:
      print "From class test"
  obj = TEST()

`not getting proper indentation`

I am expecting that it should print the line that I have written in `__init__.py` file but it is not printing that line

What mistake I am doing

Comment: Is your file named `init.py` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes it is __init__.py. typo

Comment: stackoverflow changes __ to bold

Answer (score 1):

> What mistake I am doing

Messing with `__init__.py`... It is best kept empty, unless you understand and want/need to use a package.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages for reference.

Comment: I need something which should be called everytime when i call the script

Comment: That is the reason I thought of putting this in `__init__`.py file

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is `this`?

Comment: I am working on logging module and creating some default handlers. I want that piece of code to execute when user run his script. That is the reason I have added in init.py file thinking that i executes everytime when python script is triggererd

Comment: Even I  checked pymodbus library and they did the same in init.py